# Period of oscilation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, spring

Two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ are connected by a spring of spring constant $k$ and slide freely without friction along horizontal track. What is period of oscillation? No force influence.

Comment: Hi user1872329. Welcome to Physics.SE. This site deals with conceptual Physics Q&A. We don't encourage homework questions that doesn't involve any sort of work done by the *author* and asks other users to solve the problem. If you think you could clarify your question, add *what you've done* along with your question. We're ready to help you. If you aren't clear, Please have a look at our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/11062) for more info.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us at least a force balance or some effort to get an answer?

Comment: You should do a dynamic analysis of the system and find the reduced mass of the system.Or you can work with energies(o.5(m1+m2)*V^2=0.5Kx^2.From there you should find the velocity and proceed in finding the time that it gets to do a whole oscilation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Reduced Mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass) to tackle such problems.

Now just see this as a simple spring mass system with mass as reduced mass like this one.
Where the hanging mass is equivalent reduced mass.

[image]

Comment: Starting the solution this problem from the reduction of masses is not the best idea. It is necessary to write equations of dynamics first.

Comment: Hmm.. I have never been able to complete it using equations myself without mistake .So, i don't suggest it. :P